# Take elements from list and add them in pairs recursively F#

Tags: list, f#, tuples

I have just started my F# adventure and am stuck. I want to write a recursive function that takes the elements from a list, add them in pairs and returns the list - int list->(int*int) list

So like this:
[x1; x2; x3; x4] = [(x1,x2);(x3,x4)]

This is what I have right now.

```
let rec combinePair xs = 
    match xs with
    |[] -> []
    |[x] -> [x]
    |x::y::xs' ->  (x,y)::combinePair xs'
```

This does not work, but I feel it may be close to the answer. I just don't how to continue from here. As I am still trying to learn I hoped that maybe one could point me in the right direction instead of giving me the full answer

Cheers

Comment: You are close. What should the function do on lists that contains odd elements? It boils down to the `[x]` case.

Comment: If it contains odd elements it should just ignore that element altogether. [x1; x2; x3] = [(x1,x2)]

Comment: This is not how the code above works though. If you change it to work like that it should work for you.

Comment: Ahh i see. I have been completly blind to my error. Thank you a lot. I was very close indeed: This was the one causing the problem |[x] -> [x] and should be changed to |[x] -> []

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was very close to the answer. I forgot to add what would happen in cases of the list containing an odd number of elements. In my case I just wanted it to get rid of the last element. This is the solution

```
let rec combinePair xs = 
  match xs with
  | [] -> []
  | [x] -> []
  | x::y::xs' -> (x,y)::combinePair xs'
```